# Android MVVM, Single Activity Architecture, What is the best class to store data

Tags: android, mvvm, singleton, clean-architecture

When using MVVM pattern and SingleActivityArchitecture in Android, What is the best class to store data that is used everywhere?

My Architecture is:

```
SplashFragment(SplashViewModel)───-┌──> MainActivity(MainViewModel)  
LoginFragment(LoginViewModel)───--─┤  
HomeFragment(HomeViewModel)  ───---┘
```

> And, All viewmodels depend on a repository using for request remote data.

For example

1. Users login at LoginFragment using LoginViewModel's function.
2. Stores the data returned from the login progress in ***CLASS X***
3. Move To Home
4. HomeViewModel requests to remote data source using the data in ***CLASS X***

What is the best class for ***X***? Repository? MainViewModel? New singleton class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a shared database (personally, I use [Realm](https://realm.io))

In your example, it would work like this:

1. User logs in, `LoginViewModel` opens the Realm database and stores access token etc.
2. Each time another fragment or service needs this data, it simply opens the database and fetches it.

Using a singleton class is also an option, however one of the downsides to this is that it won't be persisted between the app being relaunched.

You should also take note of the various pros and cons of using the singleton pattern as described [here](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2020/05/12/singleton-pattern-evil-or-misused/).

Another more recent option would be to scope your view model to the activity or navigation graph instead of to a fragment, as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel).

Comment: Thank you. Using db would be one way too!